# building a .net project with a COM reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, com, com-interop

My .net project references a COM type library which I registered on my developer machine(I don't have control over this one).
It looks like VS2010 generates interop assemblies on the fly - 2 different(they really differ) for Release and Debug.
These are put in /obj/Release and /obj/Debug folders respectively.
The thing is that the COM library is not and should not be registered on the build machine.

What are my options here?
I don't feel like putting the /obj/Release(Debug) folders with the interop assemblies under source control. If I have to do that I would like to change the paths but I don't see any way to do that.

If I have to use tlbimp to generate the IA's myself how do I generate the 2(Debug and Release) versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an interop assembly manually by using [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx), and then reference those assemblies instead of the actual COM library. This means Visual Studio does not have to generate the interop-assemblies and you have full control over them. You would have to check these in of course, but then you can put them anywhere you want.

**Edit:**

Since the interop assembly contains only metadata, that is to say no executable code, there should be no difference between a "Release" or "Debug" build, in fact *tlbimp.exe* does not have options to specify either.

Comment: The 2 IAs do differ - I compared them with a diff tool. But thanks for  the answer anyway, I guess I don't have better options.

Comment: That's interesting... I wonder why they differ, what causes the difference and what the difference actually might be... Will let you know if I find something out.